# Solving second degree simultaneous equation

Tags: math, algebra

What would be the solution to the following two equations ?

A<sub>1</sub>uv + B<sub>1</sub>u + C<sub>1</sub>v + D<sub>1</sub> = 0

A<sub>2</sub>uv + B<sub>2</sub>u + C<sub>2</sub>v + D<sub>2</sub> = 0

u, v in [0, 1]

The solution needs to be blazing fast because it needs to be solved for each pixel, hopefully a direct rather than iterative solution.

This is basically trying to find the inverse of a coons patch where the boundaries are straight lines.

Comment: What are you trying to solve for?

Comment: @John:  They have that?!  Awesome, thanks for the link!

Comment: type it into wolframalpha.com

Comment: @chris u and v is what I am trying to solve for.

Comment: Mathoverflow would reject a question like this. It's geared toward math *research* questions.  I don't know of a site for math questions like this that are not trivial but not research-level either.

Comment: If enough people voted for it, maybe SO would open up a medium level/applied math stack exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve equation 1 for u, you get `u = (-C_1v -D_1)/(A_1v+B_1)`.  Substitute that into equation 2, multiply through by `(A_1v+B_1)`, and you should get a quadratic in v.  Use the quadratic equation to solve for v.

Bonus points for figuring out what happens when `A_1v+B_1` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

I used wolfram alpha.

The generic form timed out while calculating, but I did get a solution substituting one constant with a number.

The resulting solution was pages long :P.

I thing I will have to go with some other solution that approximates u,v, the direct solution will be too slow for a per pixel approach.